# You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. Google Places API in Android apps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places API in a very simple app. I just want to locate all the shopping malls near the current location. I used this web service:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.9412390245245,77.6171295438685&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=shopping_mall&key=MY_SERVER_KEY

It was working, but i am getting the following error message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

How can I avoid this?,And heard that

**For Google Places API it's 2500 requests per day and 10 requests per second**,

But today i requested below 15 requests then what is problem i am not understanding

Can some one help me please?

Comment: Google API has limited quota for day. It will be set to next day. if you want to use more quota then you have to buy it

Comment: when you are accessing google API's for free , you will be having a fix amount of hits. check this link for more details - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Comment: Let me correct you. Google place api provides 1000 requests per day for free not 2500. You can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) for more info.

Comment: Jaydip kalkani but today i just request 10 times as you said i have chance for 1000 request right?

Comment: matin sayyad i know this but there is some free quota i mean 1000 request free per day,But today i just used 10 requests

Comment: You can check your requests traffic for today in your developer console. For monitor how many request you have sended today, navigate to [this](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/placesandroid.googleapis.com/overview?) link or open your developer console-->>library->>search "google places api for android"-->>click on search result-->>Manage and on that page you can see your requests.

Comment: `but today i just request 10 times` that is what *you think*. But probably you implemented your code incorrectly, and it could do much more requests.

Comment: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko i used above code

Comment: you didn't show any code above

Comment: i mean i followed this tutorial 
 https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko is it not correct implementation?

Comment: Still i did not get clarity about this,If some one clarify it will be helpfull to me

Comment: Log into the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places-backend.googleapis.com/quotas), select the project where you have created the API key, and check how many requests you have sent to the Places API. If another application is using API keys in the same project, that will also count against the daily 1K limit

Comment: If you would like an extension of the limit, you can log onto the google developer console and just add credit card information. This can increase your free tier limit to up to 250k requests.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

You must be using Places Search/ Places Radar (deprecated) for populating this. The limit 2500 requests and on the link provided you can read that Places Search uses up 10 requests. You can increase the usage to 150,000 by putting in your Credit Card details, purely for identity verification (it is still free).